# LinkedIn Profile Widget Breaking Website CSS

Tags: css, linkedin-api

When embedding the profile widget within a website it breaks the CSS of the page. You can see an example here: https://www.pinkconnect.com/local/twickenham/ all visited links are purple but that is from a style sheet loaded from static.licdn.com
If we remove the LinkedIn Profile Widget all links are acting normally.

Any idea why the CSS would not be constrained to the elements it is creating for the widget?

[image: Screenshot of visited link colour]

Comment: Because of visited link change color pink to purple thats why different color show

Simple,just add this css for visited link color

.fusion-content-boxes a:visited {
    color: #e91e63;
}

Comment: @SatishModha Thanks for your thoughts, but I don't get why adding the LinkedIn profile widget is making these changes? Sure it should be contained to only affect things it adds to the page?